# What are the penalties and bureaucratic hurdles when overstaying a tourist visa in Cambodia?

Tags: visas, overstaying, cambodia, polish-citizens

I have a Cambodian (ordinary) visa valid until September 17. However I will leave Cambodia on September 18 evening or September 19 morning. [On this website](http://www.travelfish.org/visas/cambodia) it is written that it would cost me $6 per day.

But I would like to ask someone who did it recently. Is it really completely hassle-free and easy?

I want to travel to Vietnam via a land crossing. But I'm also interested in the situation on other borders / airport.

Comment: For completeness sake, what's your nationality?

Comment: I'm from Poland

Comment: Do you intend to go back to Cambodia?

Comment: In early November, maybe I'll be going from Vietnam to Thailand. I do not want to lose the possibility to do it by land.

Comment: Overstays are never "hassle-free", they are usually noted in your passport and every immigration official in the future will see that you have overstayed before, hence are a potential risk for overstaying again.  Is staying one more day in Cambodia worth the risk?  Only you can decide that.

Comment: Did you end up overstaying? What was the penalty?

Comment: Finally changed plans, extended visa etc. So I don't know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **It’s not advisable, but you can overstay your Cambodian visa at a cost of $5 a day for the first 30 days and $6 a day after that**, payable at Immigration on your way out of the country.
>
> If you plan to only stay a few days more than 30, this is often cheaper than getting a visa extension. However, be warned that you’ll need exact change in US dollars. If you present them with a $20 bill for a $15 overstay, it’s very likely that you won’t be given change.
>
> The Cambodia government immigration site says that overstayers are also liable to pay the cost of an extended visa, but in practice overstayers are only charged the $5- or $6-per-day fee.

[Details here](http://www.movetocambodia.com/planning-your-move-to-cambodia/cambodia-visas/)

[Similar information can be found here](http://www.backpackingasia.com/TestUserInterface/ArticleContent.aspx?Art=19&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

***DISCLAIMER*** - Obviously, there can be further troubles if this gets noted in your passport, so the advice is for you to contact the nearest concerning embassy, consulate or immigration office for the latest up-to-date information. An overstay can harm your chances of getting a future visa for this country, and may do so also for other countries.

Comment: Might be worth noting that a recorded overstay *anywhere* can effect your future chances of getting visas - mostly for that country, but also potentially for others.

Comment: Do you think I should make that clearer in my answer? @CMaster

Comment: I'd mention the potential consqeuences explicitly, yes.

Comment: Edited slightly @CMaster

Comment: Just went and overstayed 60 days. It was 10usd a day. Also date on the visa was not the length of visa validity but date when you can enter. The date on entry exit stamp is how long you can stay. Could re enter without any problems. They told me overstay doesn't matter as long as tiu pay the fine

Comment: @HMR you should add a separate answer